# How to place the header at the center of the table row?

Tags: html, css

This is what I have now!

```css
.overzicht td{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<table class='overzicht' border='1'>
  <tr style='background-color: yellow;'>
    <td colspan='9'>
      <h2 style='margin-top: auto; '> Meest recente storing </h2>
      <form method='POST' action='nieuwestoring.php' style='float: right;   margin-bottom: 0px;'>
        <input type='submit' style='padding: 10px;' name='nieuw' value='Nieuwe Storing'>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How do I place the header text at the same height as the button?
So it's not above the button?

Comment: you want to make the title and button in same line?

Comment: .overzicht h2 {
  display:inline;
} or inline-block...

Comment: @AzeezKallayi Yes!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```css
.overzicht td{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 600px;
}

.overzicht h2 { 
    display:inline; 
    line-height: 39px;
 }
```

```html
<table class='overzicht' border='1'>
    <tr style='background-color: yellow;'>
        <td colspan='9'>
            <h2 style='margin-top: auto; '> Meest recente storing </h2>
            <form method='POST' action='nieuwestoring.php' style='float: right; margin-bottom: 0px;'>
                <input type='submit' style='padding: 10px;' name='nieuw' value='Nieuwe Storing'>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you can also add ` margin-bottom:0;line-height:39px`  on `h2` so that the `h2` will be aligned with the `button` also vertically

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks :)

Comment: @PatrickMlr is it possible to center the text horizontally in the table row with the button not counted?

Comment: @JelleBotman See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5m7ygvv/). I just added a minus margin to the form.

Comment: The button is not inside the table row

Comment: @JelleBotman Oh god, sorry. This was a old version. Look at this: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5m7ygvv/3/). To change the position, just change the margin-left inside of the html.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

HTML

```
    <table class='overzicht' border='1'>
    <tr style='background-color: yellow;'>
  <td><h2 style='margin-top: auto; '> Meest recente storing </h2></td>
        <td>
            <form method='POST' action='nieuwestoring.php' style='float: right;   margin-bottom: 0px;'>
              <input type='submit' style='padding: 10px;' name='nieuw' value='Nieuwe Storing'>
            </form>
        </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table.overzicht{
      max-width: 600px;
      min-width: 600px;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .overzicht td{
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align:center;
      border:0px;    
    }
    .overzicht td h2{
      margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: try to use the code snippet, so i can see the result directly

Comment: Please refer this link

Answer (score 0):

based on your last comment I update patrick's answer

I have apply position absolute to button

```css
.overzicht td{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 600px;

position: relative;
}

.overzicht h2 { 
    display:inline; 
    line-height: 39px;
 } 
form{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class='overzicht' border='1'>
    <tr style='background-color: yellow;'>
        <td colspan='9'>
            <h2 style='margin-top: auto; '> Meest recente storing </h2>
            <form method='POST' action='nieuwestoring.php' style='margin-bottom: 0px;'>
                <input type='submit' style='padding: 10px;' name='nieuw' value='Nieuwe Storing'>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```